# What version of the LoTR film shows Gandalf breaking Saruman's staff?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf, saruman

In the book version, Gandalf confronts Saruman and declares "Your staff is broken," at which point Saruman's staff shatters.

I just re-watched the movie version on DVD, and that scene isn't shown. Instead, Gandalf says Saruman has no more power" or some such, and there is no direct confrontation between the two wizards after Gandalf becomes Gandalf the White.

However, there is a Youtube video I found that is closer to the scene from the book. What version of the movie has that scene in it?

Comment: What's the reason you accepted the answer you did? It doesn't actually provide any evidence of what version the scene is in unlike the other answer.

Comment: It was first, and answered my question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That scene is from the [Extended Editions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000654ZK0) of *The Lord of The Rings* series.

> The success of the theatrical cuts brought about four-disc Extended Editions, with new editing, added special effects and music. The extended cuts of the films and the included special features were spread over two discs, and a limited collector's edition was also released
>    <sub>- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_(film_series)#Home_media)</sub>

The scene in question:

Comment: Interesting. Was the scene re-shot, or was it filmed during the making of the original but cut during editing>

Comment: @DuncanC - I think most of the extra scenes in the Extended Editions was old footage, although Jackson did shoot new some material for them. I'm not positive about this scene in particular though, but my guess is old footage.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that scene was indeed from the Extended Edition? You quote the extended edition had extra material but nothing specific mentions this scene.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I got the extended edition on blu-ray and it is in there, not as a separate scene, but as a part of the whole movie. Is that proof enough?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid FWIW I believe this answer is correct but we generally try and provide evidence here, such as in the other answer. Someones word the answer is correct is evidence but how trustworthy? Well, we don't know.

Comment: It's been quite a few years since I've read the books, and now I can't find my copies. :(. What chapter contains the "Your staff is broken" scene? That's well before "The Scouring of the Shire", isn't it? I seem to remember it as being not too long after the Ents destroy Isngard.

Comment: Is there an edition other than the theatrical and extended editions?  The question is being asked because it was not in the theatrical edition, so wouldn't that make it the extended edition by default?

Answer (score 50):

### [Scene 4: The Voice of Saruman](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings:_The_Return_of_the_King_(extended_edition)#New_Scenes)

This scene was cut from the original film, and was later added into the extended edition from the film, it was one of 4 scenes that were cut entirely from the second half of *The Return of the King*.

The decision to remove the scene on the cutting room floor was explained by Peter Jackson in a 2003 interview with *Ain't It Cool News*:

> "The trouble is, when we viewed various ROTK cuts over the last few weeks, it feels like the first scenes are wrapping last year's movie, instead of starting the new one. We felt it got Return Of The King off to an uncertain beginning, since Saruman plays no role in the events of ROTK (we don't have the Scouring later, as the book does), yet we dwell in Isengard for quite a long time before our new story kicks off.
>
> "**We reluctantly made the decision to save this sequence for the DVD.** The choice was made on the basis that most people will assume that Saruman was vanquished by the Helm's Deep events, and Ent attack. We can now crack straight into setting up the narrative tension of ROTK, which features Sauron as the villain."
> <sub>[The Guardian - Jackson defends Saruman cuts](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2003/nov/11/lordoftherings.news)</sub>

A description of the differences can be found on [Movie Censorship](https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=1902), which also discusses it's removal from the film on the cutting room floor.

The scene can be found on youtube, shown below

---

Christopher Lee's reaction to Jackson cutting his final scene out of the film was rather dramatic, causing a falling out between the two before a rekindling. The clip below shows his thoughts after rekindling his relationship with Peter Jackson and talks about it rather jokingly:

From a 2003 Sky News article, Lee expressed his surprise to his removal and his mood on the premiere:

> "Of course I am very shocked, that's all I can say."

> "No, what's the point? What's the point of going? None at all."
> <sub>[Sky News - Christopher Lee axed from film finale - Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20040812135031/http://www.sky.com/skynews/article/0,,30500-12925257,00.html)</sub>

Comment: Nice answer. Wasn't Christopher Lee upset by the decision to cut this scene?

Comment: I understand the need to cut material so the movie isn't 15 hours long, but this scene seems really important. (Although, as @Pryftan points out, it would have been better if it was more true to the book.)

Comment: It’s not very important in the way Peter Jackson wanted to end the second film and start the third film, that’s quite clearly laid out in the quote imo. PJ acknowledges that it was a significant plot point within the scope of the entirety of the book (read: for the Scouring of the Shire to make sense) but within the story PJ was telling it made no difference.

Comment: @RedCaio yes, Christopher Lee was indeed annoyed, as it cut him out of the third film almost entirely (no scouring). I’ll add the quote in a bit.

Comment: Even if you cut "The Scouring of the Shire" the way the original DVD was done was unsatisfying. Saruman was left in his tower, with his staff, and would still represent a very real threat. At least with the "Your staff is broken" bit it would be clear that Saruman's leadership of the wizards had ended.

Comment: It is up to PJ to tel the story that he wanted to tell, @Duncan, not me. I merely provide the information.